# How to make grease pencil draws permanent?

Tags: grease-pencil

I am using the grease pencil during animation creation to mark some specific places. However, some drawings dissapear everytime if I change to another frame.

Is it possible to make them persistent?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, you have to go to the right menue and press on the button `Frame locked`

[image]

Comment: Note that this will overwrite any other strokes painted in the frames other than active when you pressed Lock. Hence only one frame of the GP will be visible